# Which network costs apply when communicating between App Engine & Compute Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I am running a Java HDR application on Google's App Engine and I want to add a backend service that is running on the Compute Engine. I'll most likely be communicating between these two with either [URL Fetches](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) or [Sockets](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/). The GCE instance will be running in the US.

The [Compute Engine pricing site](https://developers.google.com/compute/pricing#network) states several different egress costs for different zones, services and regions. Unfortunately I was unable to find any information on which one will span between an App Engine and a Compute Engine instance.

**Which networking costs will arise? Which type of network spans between GAE & GCE? What does the pricing site mean when referring to zones, service, regions?**

Thanksalot!